# reference problems system.net.http nuget package 4.3.1 coul not load system.net.http 4.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservices-client

I am trying to create a library to call web services, its pretty simple, I have:
1.library of class proyect framework 4.6.1
2.From nugget I add the Newtonsoft.Json  v10.0.2
3.FRom nugget I add the System.Net.Http v4.3.1
4. FRom nugget I add  System.Net.Http.Formating.Extention v5.2.3

I got this function:

```
        static async public Task<ObservableCollection<CProyecto>> GetProyectos()
        {
        try
        {
            using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            { 
        ...........
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Error = e.Message;
        }
        return something;
    }
```

When I run I got a runtime error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

I really dont know what to do,... I've try using older versions bu I got the same error

Any Idea ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day I've found the problem,... maybe will be useful to someone:
I have a ViewModel Project referencing to my "problematic" project (ServiceCaller Project)
The error was located on the ViewModel project. It has a reference to the System.Net.Http 4.0.0.  I just delete the reference to that assembly and all is working now.